# Ajax takes time, thus gets wrong variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have a for loop, and inside that for loop, I am setting a variable. Again, within the same loop, I am doing another loop and perform an ajax call. My problem is that, it takes time to come to the success callback, thus my variable above changes in the meantime, which creates a bug. I created a demonstration:

```
 var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// I have a for here {
    var item = items[i];       

   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {


        $.ajax({
           url: '/search',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(item);
           }
        })
    }
 }
```

`Item` returns the same value of 6 at the same time

---

Edit: I tried passing in value like this, but didn't work:

```
   $.ajax(item, {
        url: '/search',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, item) {
             console.log(item);
        }
     })
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `albumImg`?

Comment: you may have added another one. Is it `item` or `items`?

Comment: Yes, fixed it now. Sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the crazy scoping rules surrounding the `var` keyword, there is only one `item`. You are just changing the value of the existing item.

If you are targeting an environment that supports ES6, you can instead use the keyword `let`.

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     let item = items[i];

     $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             console.log(item);
        }
     })
 }
```

`let` is block scoped, while `var` is function scoped. The `let` keyword would ensure there is a different instance on each loop.

If you want a solution which would work on old browsers:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     var item = items[i];

     var handlerFunction = (function(item) {
          return function(data) { 
             console.log(item);
          }
     })(item);

     $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        dataType: "json",
        success: handlerFunction 
     })
 }
```

In this solution, we've created an anonymous function and passed `item` to it. The `item` parameter inside this function belongs to this function, and is not going to be changed by the outside `item` object changing.

You may say "but handler function is also scoped with the `var` keyword". But that's OK, because on each iteration of the loop `handlerFunction` is passed as a parameter to the `ajax` method before being reassigned a different anonymous function.

---

Your question triggered me to ask how typescript deals with block-scoped variables inside a loop, if it had to generate ES5-targeted javascript.

Interestingly, this block of code:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     let item = items[i];
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`timeout function: item=${item}`);
    }, 100);
 }
```

Compiles to this javascript

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var _loop_1 = function () {
    var item = items[i];
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("timeout function: item=" + item);
    }, 100);
};
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    _loop_1();
}
```

So the typescript compiler uses an enclosing function to ensure that each `item` is unique.

Comment: it makes ajax call six times. So try to make a single ajax call.